# Mod-rewrite rule for external pages?

Tags: mod-rewrite, cross-domain

Is it possible use mod_rewrite to resolve addresses hosted on another server?

Say I want to setup this URL:

```
http://www.myserver.com/myfolder/
```

To actually resolve to:

```
http://www.anotherserver.com/anotherfolder/
```

If so, could you provide a RewriteRule example?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [*P* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) in a [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rule to get that substitution URL requested by [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^myfolder/$ http://other.example.com/anotherfolder/ [P]
```

Now when a client is requesting `/myfolder/` from your server, it will request `http://other.example.com/anotherfolder/` and send the response from that server back to the client.

Comment: Worth noting that you need to include mod_proxy_http module now also.

Comment: @Christian can you provide more details with what you mean by "include mod_proxy_http module"?

Comment: Hi @user1111929, see here; https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_http.html - This module needs to be enabled before this rewrite will work.

Comment: According to the documentation If he just wants redirect then the [P] flag is not necessary - the [P] does it via internal proxy whereas the without it just does an external redirect.. but maybe I misunderstand what he means with "resolve"

Answer (score 3):

No, tunneling is not possible, you'd have to use a CGI script for this. However, you can *redirect*:

```
RewriteRule  ^(.*)  http://new.example.com/$1
```

with or without the [R] flag, and it will automatically redirect the user to the new domain.

**Edit:** Apparently it is possible to tunnel requests with `mod_proxy` and the `[P]` flag. See Gumbo’s answer.

Comment: Cool thanks, the user would see the refresh in this case? (ie: address bar will show http://new.example.com). When you say i'd need a CGI script, could you give me some clues as to what i should look for ? cheers

Comment: Yes, the user would see the new URL. If you don't want this, google (or search on StackOverflow) for "proxy software".

Comment: Wouldn't the [P] flag allow tunnelling, or rather... proxying?

Answer (score -1):

Hey I tried rewrite and didn't work (just tested in localhost)

Also I find this easy way

```
Redirect /myfolder external_url
```

Comment: Why the downvotes ? Although it doesn't use `mod_rewrite`, it works like a charm.