# htaccess image redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have 20 million images spread across 3 subdomains.  Here is an example:

subdomain3.domainabc.com/images/image5.jpg

I do not wish to move these images to my new server/domain and I do not wish to link to them directly.  Instead, I want to use my htaccess file on domainxyz.com.  So, on domainxyz.com when this image is called:

subdomain3.domainxyz.com/images/image5.jpg

It goes to server domainabc.com and displays the correct image.  Is this possible?  Here is what I've put into domainxyz.com htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domainxyz\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.jpg$ http://%1\.domainabc\.com/$1\.jpg [R,L]
```

Comment: You probably want to take a look at [`using mod_rewrite for Proxying`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html).  Though you may want to instead redirect all the images to a script that fetches and returns the proper image depending on your exact needs.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: [Mod-rewrite rule for external pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699861/mod-rewrite-rule-for-external-pages)

Tunneling is not possible; only redirecting.

Comment: So, does that mean that what I'm trying to accomplish can not be done?