# How to rewrite url out site

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have 2 domain, but use 1 database..
I want rewrite path file image.
But error 500.
Please help me!

```
RewriteRule ^img/video/([^/]*)\.jpg$ http:\/\/example.com\/upload\/video\/$1.jpg [L]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mod-rewrite rule for external pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699861/mod-rewrite-rule-for-external-pages)

Comment: Check your Apache error.log and see what the actual error is.

Comment: This ok, but i use codeigniter... RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^img/video/([^/]*)\.jpg$ http://phim18.biz/upload/video/$1.jpg [L]
------------
Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to escape `/` when rewriting:

```
RewriteRule ^img/video/([^/]*)\.jpg$ http://example.com/upload/video/$1 [L]
```

will work.

Comment: This oke, but i use codeigniter 
RewriteRule ^img/video/([^/]*)\.jpg$ http://example/upload/video/$1.jpg [L]
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L]
... It show error